# DIV is not as wide as the page in Chrome (mobile) when a long word overflows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

#### Case 1: Without `initial-scale=1.0`

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .header {
        background: green;
        color: white;
        height: 2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <p>
      Veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongword
    </p>
</html>
```

I open this page with Chrome on a desktop browser. Then I right click the page and select `Inspect`. Then I click the mobile icon in the inspector and select `Galaxy S5` from the dropdown. I see this:

[image]

The same result is reproducible with Chrome on actual mobile phone. The `<div>` element is not as wide as the page.

#### Case 2: With `initial-scale=1.0`

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .header {
        background: green;
        color: white;
        height: 2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <p>
      Veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongword
    </p>
</html>
```

Here is the output now. The page seems okay when it loads but as we scroll right, we see that the `<div>` is still not as wide as the entire width of the page.

[image]
[image]

Output in both cases remain the same even if I add `width: 50%` to the `.header` in the CSS.

#### Question

Why does this issue occur? How can I fix it such that the `<div>` element is really as wide as the page and the entire long word is visible to the right (it is okay if the user has to scroll right to see the long word)?

Comment: Did you try just to put a `width: 100%` (or 100vw) ?

Comment: You are dealing with _overflow_ here; the element the text is in doesn’t extend its width - so child elements inheriting this width, don’t become wider either. Solution is to force such long words to break, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: @AndréDS Yes, I tried both `width: 100%` and `width: 100vw`. It did not affect the results. I still get the same behavior I have shown in the screenshots.

Comment: @04FS `overflow-wrap: break-word` solves the problem (causes the long word to wrap thereby avoiding the overflow issue). For some reason though, `overflow-wrap: anywhere` makes no difference. You could add your comment as an answer so that your answer can be selected to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with *overflow* here; the element the text is in doesn’t extend its width - so child elements inheriting this width, don’t become wider either.

Solution (or workaround, depending how you want to see it) is to force such long words to break, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

If you check the browser compatibility table further down that page, you’ll see that the value `anywhere` doesn’t have browser support yet, expect for Firefox 65+ - but for most cases, `break-word` should do.

(You can also check out the similar property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break Sometimes a combination of both can lead to better results in older browsers.)